# Date warnings, cannot use web or update software

Tags: updates

I’m getting date warnings from different parts of the OS:

- Multiple websites give warnings about SSLs being out of date
- Cannot use the App update system as the error says there’s an SSL error

The clock is set correctly.

What should I do next to debug or try and fix the problem?

Currently using OS 5.

Comment: If the system time appears correct, then you may need to also confirm the time reported by the UEFI/BIOS. Does your computer have multiple OSes installed?

Comment: @matigo yeah I do – also have Windows, but the clock on that appears correct also, and I’ve had them both installed for quite a while now.